# How to fix a SQL Join query on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on MySQL Workbench and A SQL join query is not working for me.

```
SELECT OI.OrderName, count(OI.OrderNo)
FROM onns.es_orderInfo as OI 
JOIN onns.es_order as O
ON  OI.OrderNo = O.OrderNo
JOIN onns.es_orderGoods OG
ON O.OrderNo = OG.OrderNo
GROUP BY OI.OrderName;
```

I don't get any response; the code keeps running.

Could anyone help me figure out my mistake?

Comment: How many records do you have for each table?

Comment: I have 268,390 records for es_order, 321,303 records for es_orderInfo, and 339,904 records for es_orderGoods.

Comment: There's no mistake, it's just a very heavy query due to the cardinalities of your tables. It will eventually stop and get you the output.

Comment: If you don't use indices yet, you can significantly speed up your query with them, it's sufficient to apply them onto the columns of your join conditions.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images, perhaps more easily done in the command line client than in workbench) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all the tables in the query and `explain SELECT...rest of your select`.  you are likely missing some obvious index, since you don't have all that many records.

Comment: also please explain which of the three tables might have more than one record for a given orderNo.